# Is it possible for React data to persist upon reload if the value is boolean?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I am a newbie, so apologies if this is a silly question. I am working on a simple "like/unlike" button for a React/Redux app I am building. The button is operational, updates state accordingly, etc. However, upon reload it will (obviously) not persist the boolean value. I've attempted localStorage and would be okay using Redux / passing it to my Rails API (but again, not sure how to do with boolean values). Any insight would be super helpful! Thank you.

```
 import React from 'react'

class LikeButton extends React.Component { 

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            liked: false
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState ({
            liked: !this.state.liked
        })
    }

    render() {
        let label = this.state.liked ? "♥" : "♡";
        return ( 
        <button className="like-button" onClick={this.handleClick} id={this.props.recipeId}>{label}</button>
        )
    }
}

export default LikeButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can persist your Redux state in the local storage, by setting a simple state update listener. Then you could intialize your Redux state with the local storage version. Dan Abramov made a course about this : https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-persisting-the-state-to-the-local-storage.

Here is the code from this course :

```
// localStorage.js
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};

export const saveState = (state) => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState);
  } catch {
    // ignore write errors
  }
};

// store.js
import throttle from 'lodash.throttle';
...

// get persisted value
const persistedState = loadState();
const store = createStore(
  app,
  persistedState
);

// avoid too frequent saves
store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
  saveState({
    todos: store.getState().todos
  });
}, 1000));
```